# Wildcard for WHERE?

Tags: mysql, search, wildcard, contains

I want to setup code that does this: (* is wildcard)

```
SELECT * FROM * WHERE * CONTAINS '$search-query';
```

What MYSQL code can I use to acheive this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project called [anywhereindb](http://code.google.com/p/anywhereindb) which can do what you want.

---

I am not going to create a full solution, its going to take a long time, but, I am going to create an example of what you would called

```
SELECT * From `tablename` WHERE * CONTAINS `$search_query`
```

First, lets extract the fields

```
$fields = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM `yourtable` LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
    $info = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    $fields[] = $info -> name;
}
```

Now prepare your query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE";
foreach($fields as $index => $field) {
    $fields[$index] = $field." CONTAINS '$search_query'"
}
$query .= implode(" and ", $fields);
//Finally query
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: That won't work. I need something I can directly implement into my site. I want to stick strictly to PHP. I need something I can run directly through the mysql_query command.

Comment: @SamClark, Check the update. Thats the best I will give to this question. Please dont mind.